# Is there script logic where I can keep only the first two lines of a file and comment out the rest of the lines?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

So I was working on script where Iam deleting the last two/one lines/line from my file
I have a used a for loop and kept sed inside it (I know it might not be the best way) but since my file can have maximum 6-7 lines , I used it.
Now Iam searching for a way where , instead of deleting , I comment out 'n' number of lines below the first two lines.

```
For eg : If my test file contains entry 

First Line 
Second Line 
To be commented line 1
To be commented line 2
.
.
.
To be commented line n(n < 7)

#!/bin/bash



IP=$(hostname -I)
file_path="/tmp/test"
number_of_lines=`wc --lines < $file_path`
if [ $number_of_lines -eq 4 ]
then
for i in $(seq 1 2); do sed -i '$d' $file_path; done;
elif [ $number_of_lines -eq 3 ]
then
for i in $(seq 1 1); do sed -i '$d' $file_path; done;
fi
echo "$IP $HOSTNAME.yyyy.xxxx.com $HOSTNAME" >> /tmp/test
```

This code deletes the last two lines or one line depending upon the count of lines in of our file of the , I was looking for a way to **comment out n lines below the first 2 lines(Which are constant)**

Comment: Use sed ranges. Read `man sed`. `sed ‘/3,6/{s/^/#/}’` comments 4 lines below the first 2 (assuming `#` is comment). Replace `6` with `$` to comment up to the last line.

Comment: Yes I used this command , and I was able to ammend changes 
I had to save the file as well , so I used mv command in the end .. 
sed '3,6 {s/^/#/}' /tmp/test > /tmp/test2 && mv /tmp/test2 /tmp/test

Comment: Check out `sed -i`.